# Camera pose estimation problem

Tags: ros-melodic, c++, tf2, coordinate-system, pick-and-place

I am creating a Pick and Place program and need help with pose estimation. I am broadcasting on RViz the coordinates based on my YOLO detection and camera. Below is my broadcasting node.

```
void poseCallback(const aricc_vision_msgs::ObjectArray::ConstPtr& msg){
  static tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster br;
  tf2_ros::Buffer buffer ;
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

  const aricc_vision_msgs::Object& last_object = msg->objects.back();

    transformStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    transformStamped.header.frame_id = "camera_color_optical_frame"; // Camera Link used
    transformStamped.child_frame_id = last_object.name; // Object name
    transformStamped.transform.translation.x = last_object.position.x; // Object position x
    transformStamped.transform.translation.y = last_object.position.y; // Object position y
    transformStamped.transform.translation.z = last_object.position.z; // Object position z

    tf2::Quaternion q;
    q.setRPY(0, 0, last_object.orientation.z);
    transformStamped.transform.rotation.x = q.getX();
    transformStamped.transform.rotation.y = q.getY();
    transformStamped.transform.rotation.z = q.getZ();
    transformStamped.transform.rotation.w = q.getW();
    br.sendTransform(transformStamped);
   
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "object_tf2_broadcaster");
  ros::NodeHandle node;
  ros::Subscriber sub = node.subscribe<aricc_vision_msgs::ObjectArray>("/re_dl_detection/YOLOv8RotateObjectDetection/dl_output", 1000, &poseCallback);
  ROS_INFO("Object_tf2_broadcaster node starting..");
  ros::Rate rate(10000); // 10 Hz
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
};
```

Below is my program to send the coordinates to the `move_group`

```
class Localizer
{
public:
    Localizer(ros::NodeHandle& nh) : listener_(buffer_)
    {
        // Subscribe to object poses
        object_pose_sub = nh.subscribe<aricc_vision_msgs::ObjectArray>(
            "/re_dl_detection/YOLOv8RotateObjectDetection/dl_output", 1000, 
            &Localizer::objectCallback, this);

        // Advertise the localize_part service
        server_ = nh.advertiseService("localize_part", &Localizer::localizePart, this);
    }

    void objectCallback(const aricc_vision_msgs::ObjectArray::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
        if (!msg->objects.empty())
        {
            // Get the last object in the message
            last_object = msg->objects.back();
       
            object_name = last_object.name;
            object_pose.pose.position = last_object.position;
            myQuaternion.setRPY(last_object.orientation.x, last_object.orientation.y, last_object.orientation.z);
            tf2::convert(myQuaternion, object_pose.pose.orientation);
        }
    }

    bool localizePart(myworkcell_core::LocalizePart::Request& req,
                      myworkcell_core::LocalizePart::Response& res)
    {    
        geometry_msgs::PoseStamped target_pose_from_cam;
        target_pose_from_cam.header.frame_id = object_name;
        target_pose_from_cam.pose = object_pose.pose;

        ROS_INFO("Target frame: %s, Base frame: %s", target_pose_from_cam.header.frame_id.c_str(), req.base_frame.c_str());

        // Transform the pose to the target frame
        try
        {   
            res.pose = buffer_.transform(target_pose_from_cam, req.base_frame).pose;
            ROS_INFO("Transformed pose: x=%f, y=%f, z=%f", res.pose.position.x, res.pose.position.y, res.pose.position.z);

            return true;
        }
        catch (tf2::TransformException &ex)
        {
            ROS_ERROR("Failed to transform pose: %s", ex.what());
            return false;
        }
    }

private:
    ros::Subscriber object_pose_sub;
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped object_pose;
    aricc_vision_msgs::Object last_object;
    std::string object_name;
    tf2::Quaternion myQuaternion;
    ros::ServiceServer server_;
    tf2_ros::Buffer buffer_;
    tf2_ros::TransformListener listener_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "vision_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    Localizer localizer(nh);

    ROS_INFO("Vision node starting");
    
    ros::Rate rate(10); // Adjust the rate as needed

    // Don't exit the program.
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

Upon running the above node, I found the incorrect object position by looking at the transformed value. From my knowledge, the relative pose is to the camera, and the pose is to the base_link, but I can't get the pose values.